# How to access a single result of a multi result query in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Given the example query:

```
StormEvents | evaluate funnel_sequence(EpisodeId, StartTime, datetime(2007-01-01), datetime(2008-01-01), 1d,365d, EventType, dynamic(['Tornado', 'Hail']))
```

Which returns 3 table results, PrevNext, Prev and Next, how do I access in KQL only one of the results?
I'm interested in something like:

```
let PrevNext, Prev, Next = StormEvents | funnel_sequence(...);
Next | where ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in a single KQL query, unfortunately. The follow up text after the `funnel_sequence` plugin receives only the first table (`PrevNext`) as input. If it helps, you can find samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet/blob/master/client/HelloKusto/Program.cs) of how to read the different tables programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. This makes some functionality unusable in a query like fork, facet and the funnel plugin when using the query for a ADX dashboard or as an intermediate step in KQL.